# When we do apply() over a sparse matrix, it automatically convert it into a dense matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

Running the following code:

```
aa = Matrix(0, nrow = 8000000, ncol = 100000, sparse = TRUE)
object.size(aa)
# 401424 bytes
apply(aa, 1, mean)
```

I get this error:

> Error in asMethod(object) : 
>         Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_dense.c, line 105

In this case, the size of `aa` is not too large, thus I guess the `apply` function automatically convert it into a dense matrix. Is there any way to make this working? I know that `rowMeans` can easily replace `apply(aa, 1, mean)` here, but what if I want to apply with some other customized functions?

Comment: Maybe checkout the [`spam`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spam/index.html) or [`slam`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/slam/index.html) packages?

Comment: I do think the size of aa may be to large. Have you tried using a smaller matrix (e.g., 800 by 1000). Does this work? It works fine on my PC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at `apply` without the `()` you can see what actually happens when you call `apply()`

```r
function (X, MARGIN, FUN, ...) 
{
FUN <- match.fun(FUN)
dl <- length(dim(X))
if (!dl) 
    stop("dim(X) must have a positive length")
if (is.object(X)) 
    X <- if (dl == 2L) 
        as.matrix(X)
    else as.array(X)
...
```

I left off the rest, but as you can see, early on in the function call, `apply` converts the object `x` into either an array or matrix with `as.matrix` or `as.array`. This coerces `aa` from class `dgCMatrix` to class `matrix` which does not have a `sparse` argument. Essentially, your code is equivalent to running `apply()` on a regular matrix in R, however if you try

```
bb = matrix(0, nrow = 8000000, ncol = 100000)
```

you get

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 5960.5 Gb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In matrix(0, nrow = 8e+06, ncol = 1e+05) :
Reached total allocation of 8075Mb: see help(memory.size)
```

...
with some other warnings left off.

In the documentation for the `Matrix` package we have,

> Even base functions may work automagically (if they first call `as.matrix()` on their principal argument), e.g., `apply`, `eigen`, `svd` or `kappa` all do work via coercion to a “traditional” (dense) matrix.

which agrees with what was said above. The problem you are running into is that when `apply()` is called, it first creates a matrix, but the matrix it is trying to make is unreasonably large, and the function cannot be completed. If your goal is to compute custom functions on large, sparse matrices, I have a feeling you are going to have to do it without the help of the `apply()` functions.

Comment: So are you aware of any apply function specifically written for sparse dgCmatrix classes ?